Conditional expectations question in econometrics R squared proof
I'm taking an econometrics class, and my Professor included a quick proof sketch for why including independent variables increases $R^2$ (And decreases unconditional variance of CEF error). Here's their outline:
$$
\begin{align}
&\text{ Let } z = \mathbb{E}[y|x_1, x_2], \text{ with Jensen's Inequality and LIE: } \\
&  \quad \;\;\;\;\: (\mathbb{E}[z|x_1])^2 \leq \mathbb{E}[z^2|x_1]  \\
&1) \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[z|x_1])^2] \leq \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[z^2|x_1]]\\
&2) \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[z|x_1])^2] \leq \mathbb{E}[z^2]   \\
&3) \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[y|x_1]^2] \leq \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[y|x_1, x_2]^2]\\
&4) \Rightarrow Var(\mathbb{E}[y|x_1]) \leq Var(\mathbb{E}[y|x_1, x_2])
\end{align}
$$
I'm fine with the whole sketch except for the left side from $2 \rightarrow 3$. How do we go from $\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[z|x_1])^2]$ to $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[y|x_1]^2]$? Am I right that this implies $\mathbb{E}[y|x_1] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[y|x_1, x_2]|x_1]$? How does the conditional expectation work here? Thanks.

I would plug in to get
$$
\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[z|x_1])^2]=\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[y|x_1, x_2]|x_1])^2]
$$
Then, by the LIE, the smaller information set dominates, so
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[y|x_1, x_2]|x_1]=\mathbb{E}[y|x_1],
$$
which, upon resubstituting, gives you the r.h.s. of 3).
